# Clang with Address Sanitizer on Windows fails at link time

Tags: windows, clang, address-sanitizer, lld

I have the following setup:

- clang:

  ```
  clang version 16.0.6
  Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  Thread model: posix
  ```
- windows (not sure if relevant):

  ```
  Windows 10 Version 22H2 (OS Build 19045.3086)
  ```
- CMakeLists.txt:

  ```
  cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)

  project(asan-test C)

  add_executable(asan-test)

  target_sources(asan-test PRIVATE asan-test.c)
  target_compile_options(asan-test PRIVATE -fsanitize=address)
  target_link_options(asan-test PRIVATE -fsanitize=address)
  target_compile_definitions(asan-test PRIVATE _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS)
  ```
- and finally the source code file `asan-test.c`:

  ```c
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>

  int main()
  {
      const int kBufferSize = 255;
      char* buffer = malloc(kBufferSize * sizeof(char));
      FILE* fi = fopen("duck.txt", "r");

      free(buffer);
      fclose(fi);

      return 0;
  }
  ```

The second command fails at link time:

```
cmake -S . -B build-windows -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang -G "Unix Makefiles"
cmake --build build-windows
```

The output contains the following 4 warnings and 1 error:

```
lld-link: warning: CMakeFiles/asan-test.dir/asan-test.c.obj: locally defined symbol imported: malloc (defined in clang_rt.asan-x86_64.lib(asan_malloc_win.cpp.obj)) [LNK4217]
lld-link: warning: CMakeFiles/asan-test.dir/asan-test.c.obj: locally defined symbol imported: free (defined in clang_rt.asan-x86_64.lib(asan_malloc_win.cpp.obj)) [LNK4217]
lld-link: warning: CMakeFiles/asan-test.dir/asan-test.c.obj: locally defined symbol imported: fclose (defined in libucrt.lib(fclose.obj)) [LNK4217]
lld-link: warning: CMakeFiles/asan-test.dir/asan-test.c.obj: locally defined symbol imported: __stdio_common_vsprintf (defined in libucrt.lib(output.obj)) [LNK4217]
```

```
lld-link: error: undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) fopen
>>> referenced by <...>\asan-test\asan-test.c:8
>>>               CMakeFiles/asan-test.dir/asan-test.c.obj:(main)
```

I'm not sure how to approach this problem. I couldn't find anything similar, or maybe I didn't look in the right places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. I came across [this page](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerWindowsPort) from the Windows port of Address Sanitizer, and the takeaway is that the Windows port...

- does not (yet) work with the debug versions of the CRT: `/MTd` and `/MDd`
- the linker does not accept `-fsanitize=address`, rather, it needs to link against, for example, `clang_rt.asan-x86_64.lib`

I changed the setup as follows:

- in `CMakeLists.txt`, I replaced

  ```
  target_link_options(asan-test PRIVATE -fsanitize=address)
  ```

  with

  ```
  target_link_libraries(asan-test PRIVATE clang_rt.asan-x86_64)
  ```
- in the cmake generation step, I added

  ```
  -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
  ```